# Dealing with NaN when calculating means

Tags: r, nan, mean, calculated-columns

I want to create a new column that contains the average two other columns. 
For example by original table (dat) looks like this:

```
    A   B
1   1   NaN
2   3   2
3   2   5
4   4   4
5   6   NaN
6   5   3
```

I now want a column C that averages A and B, so I tried the following

```
dat$C<-(dat$A + $dat$B)/2
```

But what I get is this

```
    A   B     C
1   1   NaN   NaN
2   3   2     2.5
3   2   5     3.5
4   4   4     4
5   6   NaN   NaN
6   5   3     4
```

When what I want is this

```
    A   B     C
1   1   NaN   1
2   3   2     2.5
3   2   5     3.5
4   4   4     4
5   6   NaN   6
6   5   3     4
```

So how can I calculate this new mean value column while working around the missing values in my dataset?

Comment: Try `df$C <- rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)` where `df` is your `data.frame`

Comment: @dickoa Thanks for the help. Unfortunately in my actual dataset I have other identifier columns that I'm not working into the mean so this doesn't work.

Comment: Just pass the data.frame subset to rowMeans : `dat$C <- rowMeans(dat[,c('A','B')], na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4):

You can also do

```
dat$C <- apply(dat,1,function(x) mean(na.omit(x)))
```

`na.omit` is useful to know if you want to make a more complex function since `na.omit` is from base R while `na.rm` is an argument for certain functions.